# Can we assign const char* to a string in cpp?

Tags: c++

Although my compiler doesn't throw an error while assigning const char* to a string, I am wondering if this assignment is really valid and will not throw some unexpected result

```
string name;
const char* name2 = "ABCD";

name = name2;
```

Comment: Is your question reversed? You absolutely can assign `const char*` to `std::string`, it will get copied though. The other way around requires a call to `std::string::c_str()`.

Comment: Why do you think it might _throw some unexpected result_? Constructor #4 from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) shows that there is a constructor for `string` which takes in a `const char*`, and also an `operator=` [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator=/)

Comment: @ChrisMM I guess the OP is worried that the string is storing the pointer rather than copying the characters.

Comment: @ChrisMM That constructor is not used by this code. An `operator=(const char*)` is.

Comment: @aschepler, you beat me before I could edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You absolutely can.

`std::string` was meant to replace the tedious and error-prone C strings `const char*` so for it to be a good replacement/successor it'd need backwards compatibility with `const char*` which it does.

`name = name2;`  calls `operator=` so if we check `basic_string`s overloads for this operator [we can see](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D) (3):

```
basic_string& operator=( const CharT* s );
```

<sub>Here `CharT` is of the type `char` so you get `const char*`</sub>

Which does what you'd expect it to do, it copies over the contents the `const char*` is pointing to, to the internal buffer of `std::string`:

> Replaces the contents with those of null-terminated character string
> pointed to by `s` as if by `assign(s, Traits::length(s))`.

In order to go the other route though, from a `std::string` to a `const char*`, you'd need to call its method `c_str()` on the `std::string` object.

Answer (score 3):

> I am wondering if this assignment is really valid

Yes it's valid:

```
string name;
const char *name2 = "ABCD";
name = name2;
```

Note `name = name2` calls std::string assignment operator, after which the two variables are totally independent, ie you are free to change `name`, while `name2` remains const (aka literal string).